# Conflict between filters and marker clusterer

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, filter, markerclusterer

Hi,

I'm making an interactive map on google maps API v3 (using Javascript) with filters and marker clusterer.

- Filters are working
- Marker clusterer is working too

But when I put the marker clusterer and filters together i have some troubles.

Here I put some screens about my problem in order to be more understood :
Map without any filters :
  • http://prnt.sc/dzlzhk
After filtering :
  • http://prnt.sc/dzlzog

Marker Clusterer :

```
var markerCluster = new MarkerClusterer(map, markers, 
        {imagePath: 'https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/markerclusterer/m'});
```

Function to load markers on map :

```
function loadMarkers(personList) {




    var people = ( typeof personList !== 'undefined' ) ? personList : personData;

    var j = 1; 

    for( i=0; i < people.length; i++ ) {
        var person = people[i];


        if( markerList.indexOf(person.id) !== -1 ) continue;

        var lat = person.lat,
            lng = person.lng,
            markerId = person.id;

        var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
            maxWidth: 400
        });

        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: new google.maps.LatLng( lat, lng ),
            title: person.nom,
            markerId: markerId,
            icon: markerLocation,
            map: map
        });

        markers[markerId] = marker;
        markerList.push(person.id);
```

Function to remove markers from map :

```
function removePersonMarker(id) {
    if( markers[id] ) {
        markers[id].setMap(null);
        loc = markerList.indexOf(id);
        if (loc > -1) markerList.splice(loc, 1);
        delete markers[id];
    }
}
```

Function to filter markers :

```
function filterByString( dataProperty, value ) {
    var people = [];

    for( var i=0; i < personData.length; i++ ) {
        var person = personData[i];
        if( person[dataProperty] == value ) {
            people.push( person );
        } else {
            removePersonMarker( person.id );    
        }
    }
    return people;
}
```

Marker clusterer is not updated when I use a filter and markers are displayed on the map without being clustered.

I tried all the solutions on Stack Overflow but none of them worked.

Any help is appreciate. If it could help I can post parts of the source code. Thanks.

Comment: `Here I put some screens` - a picture is worth a thousand words ... not to programmers though ... if you want **actual help** you'll need to provide **actual code**

Comment: Alright, it's done

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MarkerClusterer provides `removeMarker(s)` and `addMarker(s)` methods. Once you initialized the markerClusterer with the array you could also use this methods (instead of adding and removing them just in the list of markers) depending on the rest of the application.

The much more performant way, especially if you filter a lot of markers, is clearing the markers and add the filtered array to the markerClusterer again:

```
markerClusterer.clearMarkers();
markerClusterer.addMarkers(markers);
```

Moreover you can have a look at the `markerCluster.repaint()` method. Probably your bug is caused by this.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I'm a bit lost to integrate these methods in the code. I took an open-source code that I edited with my own filters in order to train myself with this concept before creating my own map. I understood how to filter markers but the markerCluster part seems more complex. Am I supposed to edit all the code in order to integrate these methods ? Or could clearMarkers and addMarkers easily be integrate to the code ?

Comment: After calling your `filterByString` method you have to add the `clearMarkers` and `addMarkers` part, if I see it right. The part where the filtering is called is missing. Your variable names are a bit confusing in my opinion because `markerList` is not a list of marker objects but a list of person ids.

Comment: I'll try your solution, thank you. If you want to see the entire project with my code here is the link : http://jordanj.coolpage.biz/Version%20NON-stable/
It could help you to understand

Comment: Yes...due to that behaviour it should be the missing update of the markerClusterer. Because this handles the display of the markers on the map.

Answer (score 0):

I forgot a part of the code which is useful and which contains variables of the filterByString function :

```
function filterCtrl(filterType, value) {
    var results = [];

    if( isInt(value) ) {
        filter[filterType] = parseInt(value);
    } else {
        filter[filterType] = value;
    }

    for( k in filter ) {
        if( !filter.hasOwnProperty(k) && !( filter[k] !== 0 ) ) {
            loadMarkers();
            return false;
        } else if ( filter[k] !== 0 ) {
            results.push( filterMap[k]( filter[k] ) );
        } else {
            // Nothing
        }
    }

    if( filter[filterType] === 0 ) {
        results.push( personData );
    }

    if( results.length === 1 ) {
        results = results[0];
    } else {
        results = reduceArray( results );
    }

    loadMarkers( results );
}
```

Do I have to add the methods ( clearMarkers and addMarkers ) in this function instead of the filterByString function ?

Comment: You should have put this in your question by editing it instead of posting it as a answer. I did not review your whole filter logik, but the principle is like this. 1) put all markers inside an array and add it to the markerClusterer - now they are clustered and handled by the markerClusterer 2) do the filter logic (whatever) and modify the array of markers 3) after finishing the filtering call the `clearMarkers()` method and add all filtered markers to the markerClusterer. The way you handle step two can be a bit different, but this is one possibility.